# Why are img tags, when grid-items, with height/width set to 100%, not constrained to their cell when their cell's set with fr units?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The following snippet seems to demonstrate that for an `img` tag that's a grid-item (GI), its containing-block doesn't seem to be its 'cell' when the dimension of its cell is specified in `fr` units. It seems to respect its container (its cell) when the dimension of its cell's specified in `%`. What exactly is the rule I've stumbled across here and how do people deal with it? Refrain from using `fr` units to specify the cell of GIs that're `img`?

```css
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid-container1 {
  display: grid;
  height: 10vh;
  border: dotted 1px pink;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

#grid-container2 {
  display: grid;
  height: 10vh;
  border: dotted 1px pink;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<section id="grid-container1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Panor%C3%A1mica_Oto%C3%B1o_Alc%C3%A1zar_de_Segovia.jpg">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Panor%C3%A1mica_Oto%C3%B1o_Alc%C3%A1zar_de_Segovia.jpg">
</section>
<section id="grid-container2">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Panor%C3%A1mica_Oto%C3%B1o_Alc%C3%A1zar_de_Segovia.jpg">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Panor%C3%A1mica_Oto%C3%B1o_Alc%C3%A1zar_de_Segovia.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: Please note that your HTML does not have a `#grid-container2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind it is as follows:

`1fr` is actually interpreted as if you define `minmax(auto, 1fr)`. The `minmax()` function takes two arguments and specifies that if the first argument happens to resolve to being larger than the second argument ( `auto` > `1fr` ), the whole `minmax` expression gets replaced by the first argument.

So:

```
1fr
```

actually is

```
minmax(auto, 1fr)
```

which, when `auto` is larger than `1fr`, turns into

```
auto
```

There is two ways you can resolve this:

- Either, apply an explicit `min-height` resp. `min-width` to the grid **items**.
- Or, and this is what I've been using for years, in your grid definitions, whenever there's the risk of a grid element exceeding the fractional grid track height or width, instead of `1fr` use `minmax(0, 1fr)` (or, instead of `0`, whatever is an appropriate value for the grid cell).

Comment: I think this is one of my favourite answers to any of my questions in SO - you explain the problem in depth whilst remaining clear, to the point, you provide multiple solutions & offer what solution you commonly use. Will use your profile to find similar-quality answers! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found the resource on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/)

It is because the `minimimum width` of a `flex` or `grid` item is auto, so it takes as much space as it want's as it's minimum width

> I can’t promise I’m explaining this 100% accurately, but the way I
> understand it, the minimum width of a grid column is auto. (The same
> is true for flex items, by the way.)

It can be easily solved by setting the `min-width` and `min-height` of the children of the grid element

```css
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid-container1 {
  display: grid;
  height: 10vh;
  border: dotted 1px pink;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

#grid-container2 {
  display: grid;
  height: 10vh;
  border: dotted 1px pink;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#grid-container1>*,
#grid-container2>* { /* This selector */
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="grid-container1">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Panor%C3%A1mica_Oto%C3%B1o_Alc%C3%A1zar_de_Segovia.jpg">
</section>
<section id="grid-container2">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Panor%C3%A1mica_Oto%C3%B1o_Alc%C3%A1zar_de_Segovia.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @a.mola. If anyone could elaborate on this that'd be useful. Otherwise this appears, to me, another example where CSS is unintuitive/random/non-sensical/hacky.

Comment: I've found the resource on CSS Tricks... edited my answer :D

Comment: Cool. I didn't pick up why. Hopefully it'll become apparent in the future when I learn how grid-cells can be stretched past the point specified (with `grid-template-column/row`) as I've seen that happen. Anyway, hope there aren't too many unwanted side-effects from putting `min-width: 0` on our `img` grid-items.

Comment: It’s just like the default display value of a `div` is `block` and for a span is `inline`... it’s just one of those rules that you need to remember

Comment: Please if you don’t mind... could you upvote the answer :D

Comment: Ofc. How did you come across this solution btw?

Comment: I had the same problem as you did a few months back...

Answer (score 0):

The `fr` unit, unlike percentage and pixel units, doesn't represent a length.

It represents free space.

It's also calculated last in the rendering process. (Obviously. Free space can't be known until all content is rendered.)

Well, the images are huge (3955 x 2966) and rendered first.

In the end, there's no free space, so the `fr` unit is having no effect.

With percentages you're actually setting a length, so the images can be constrained within their containers.

---

> [**§ 7.2.4. Flexible Lengths: the `fr`
> unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
>
> The distribution of leftover space occurs after all non-flexible track
> sizing functions have reached their maximum.

Comment: Are we saying that the intrinsic size of the images stretches the cell? And, by then, there's no free space? If so, is it the img's `min-width/height: auto` property & value that're responsible for stretching the cell (to the size of the image's intrinsic dimension) (as has been suggested below)?

Comment: *"Are we saying that the intrinsic size of the images stretches the cell?"* Yes.

Comment: *"And, by then, there's no free space?"* Correct.

Comment: *"If so, is it the img's `min-width/height: auto` property & value that're responsible for stretching the cell (to the size of the image's intrinsic dimension) (as has been suggested below)?"* No. It's the lack of a length limitation on `grid-template-columns`, which allows the cell to expand freely. That's why your layout works when you use `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%`, but not `1fr 1fr`.

Comment: Why does `min-width/height: 0px` applied to the grid-item make it so that `1fr` really does just make the cell span the relevant dimension of the grid-container (in this case `10vh`)?